# Session timeout

Tags: genexus

esto trabajando con Genenexus 17 U4 y hace algun tiempo me esta apareciendo este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muestro la consola tambien

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrias agregar algo mas de contexto? Es una app web, mobile al acceder a algun servicio? Te da en algun panel especifico el error? Si creas una kb nueva vacia, te funciona bien o tambien da error?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Estimados Son dos war, diferentes .pensando que era la "aplicantion Encrytion Key" las iguale con la misma llave ademas en este momento no estoy encriptando la url. cuando me da el error es cuando llamo a la transaccion